# How to autoreload temporary addon in FF 55.0.1?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

since the newest version FF 55.0.1 the add on temporary load is not reload after modify the source code. it is necessary to access at about:debugging and reload, reload and reload after all modification... Is it possible to retreive the working before this version ?

thanks !

Comment: Please describe *exactly* what you were doing which now does not work for you.

Comment: it is FF who have changed the method to refresh the temporary addon... before this version the addon was reloaded automatically after modify the code

Comment: Automatically refreshing the add-on when the add-on files changed has never been a default, unless you specifically enabled that feature, or used the [tools that specifically enabled it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext). Thus: "Please describe exactly what you were doing which now does not work for you." [Note: In some cases, newer versions of a file would be used once changed, but that was an artifact of the file being fetched form disk, not a specific effort to load a changed extension.]

Comment: "Automatically refreshing the add-on when the add-on files changed has never been a default," ... it's false ... for temporary addon it works before FF 55.0.1

Comment: Not in my experience, unless you are using a tool (e.g. [`web-ext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext) that specifically enables automatics reloading upon change. That Firefox doesn't automatically reload temporary extensions is specifically why there is a "reload" button on about:debugging for each temporary extension, [which has existed since Firefox 48](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Temporary_Installation_in_Firefox#Reloading_a_temporary_extension).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [web-ext](https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/getting-started-with-web-ext/) to achieve this. **This works in FF55+**

First of all make sure you have [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) installed (you could also use [Homebrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation) and `brew install node` on OSX).

With NodeJS in place you need to install **web-ext** via npm by typing in your terminal/cmd :

```
npm install --global web-ext
```

Then change directory to the one where your extension lives and run:

```
web-ext run
```

This will start the Firefox with your extension loaded and hot reloading enabled.

I hope this helps.